# Is there a good cheat sheet for opencv-python?

Tags: python, opencv

I have been working on a face-tracking turret with OpenCV_Python 4.1.0, but I don't know many commands and functions. So I have been looking for some documentation or a cheat sheet for OpenCV_Python that has all the possible functions and brief explanations about them.

I only found a cheat sheet for OpenCV_C++ 2.7.0, but none for OpenCV_Python.

I saw the official OpenCV 3.0.0 documentation for Python as well, but that only shows a few general-purpose functions.

Is there any source or document (or book) that I can learn all the possible functions of OpenCV_Python?

Comment: There's no cheatsheet but you can go through this [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html) to learn the general image processing tools OpenCV offers

Comment: I've been working on my project majorly based on that tutorial, but I don't know where to look for the function that erases rectangle drawn on the image with `cv2.rectangle` function. I know I could ask this here, but I thought it would be better if all the functions are explained in a certain document source so I can look that source whenever I need to find the function I need for certain situations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best documentation is the code followed by the API.  I find myself referring to the [API](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/modules.html)  frequently.  Although all of the C++ API is not available in Python, all of the Python functions can be found in the C++ API, since it is generated from them.  Additionally it is useful to know `numpy`, since the `Mat` class is represented in Python as a `numpy array`.

OpenCV is kind of a hodge podge of algorithms, there are a lot of [tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/) that are useful to go through to gain some understanding of the different capabilities available, but it isn't very linear.

If you do want something a little more organized and linear, I recommend finding a good book, I would start with Learning OpenCV, by Gary Bradski.  Although I haven't been through the latest edition, I thought the book was helpful.  There are a lot of other great books, tutorials, and blogs.  Books and blogs will fail to cover in detail every available function and algorithm, so there will still be gaps to fill.  Take your time and remember, Rome wasn't built in a day.

Comment: I was just curious about how in the world people know about OpenCV functions that weren't mentioned anywhere on the internet. But thank you!

Answer (score 7):

There is one here:
[OpenCV 4.x for Python cheat sheet](https://github.com/a-anjos/python-opencv/blob/master/cv2cheatsheet.pdf)

I hope it's useful ;)